# Windows Phone 7.5 - How to calculate route on map image?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, dictionary, navigation, routes

In my app for WP7.5, user can navigate into the university. He can see on the map his initial position acquired by scanning a Qr Code. Map image is Canvas background. Once he chooses the destination whose X and Y coordinates are known, how can I draw on the map the route from user's current location to the destination? I don't know if it is possible.

This is the working code that allows to show user's starting position on the map.

```
public void MarkLocation(ImageBrush imgmap, int posizioneX, int posizioneY)
    {
        Canvas.Background = imgmap;
        Image imgmarker = new Image();
        imgmarker.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/marker.png", UriKind.Relative));

        Canvas.SetLeft(imgmarker, posizioneX);
        Canvas.SetTop(imgmarker, posizioneY);
        Canvas.Children.Add(imgmarker);                  

    }
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw the route on the map or calculate the route in the first place? (or both?) It isn't clear from your question and they are very different tasks.

Comment: Through QR Code, user downloads the map of the building, displays it on smartphone with a marker on his starting position. Now I would like to calculate and indicate the minimun path to reach the destination chosen by user from his starting position within the building. So I'd like to draw this path on map. I'm sorry if I have not explained very well before.I hope I was clear now.

Comment: I would not try to look at doing any route navigation. Because if you are using your own image, how would the routing of the phone know where the 'obstacles' are? My suggestion, just create a small database or data file that holds all possible routes from each scan point to each destination point. You just store the XAML Path and draw that on the image.

Comment: @Flanders Sorry, still not clear. When the user scans the tag/gets the image is it based on where the user is or where they're trying to get to? How do you know where on the map the user can actually walk? I assume you want to go along paths and not through walls, etc. Do you have the routing information somewhere? If so, where and in what format? If not how do you intend to calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

If you used the [`BingMapsDirectionsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394024%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (in WP7) or the [`MapsDirectionsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (in WP8) and the user will get a full navigation experience including showing the route and you'll not need to worry about dynamically generating images or overlaying items on a Map control.

Comment: Thak you for the answer bat I can't use it because on Bing Maps there isn't my university map. So when I scan Qr Code, I can download map from server and I know my starting position.